# Django Error when change DEBUG to False

Tags: python, django

I've checked other questions here with similar title/issue but none of them seems to apply here.

I have a project in a virtual machine, and the project is running well with all features and urls working.

When I change in the `settings.py` the value of `DEBUG` from `True` to `False` and restart apache, I start receiving `500 Internal Server Error` and when I check apache log I see this error:

```
[error] ImproperlyConfigured: The included urlconf None doesn't have any patterns in it
```

but I have like 30 url's in `urls/__init__.py` (I can show full error trace if it's needed)

Does anyone can help me here ?

Full Error Trace:

```
 mod_wsgi (pid=27507): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/vagrant/products_gallery/apache/django.wsgi'.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 272, in __call__
     response = self.get_response(request)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 169, in get_response
     response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 218, in handle_uncaught_exception
     return callback(request, **param_dict)
   File "/vagrant/products_gallery/views.py", line 2844, in vhandler404
     context_instance=RequestContext(request))
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py", line 20, in render_to_response
     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 188, in render_to_string
     return t.render(context_instance)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 123, in render
     return self._render(context)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 117, in _render
     return self.nodelist.render(context)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 744, in render
     bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 757, in render_node
     return node.render(context)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 127, in render
     return compiled_parent._render(context)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 117, in _render
     return self.nodelist.render(context)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 744, in render
     bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 757, in render_node
     return node.render(context)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 159, in render
     return self.render_template(self.template, context)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 141, in render_template
     output = template.render(context)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 123, in render
     return self._render(context)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 117, in _render
     return self.nodelist.render(context)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 744, in render
     bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 757, in render_node
     return node.render(context)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 437, in render
     url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=context.current_app)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 391, in reverse
     *args, **kwargs)))
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 312, in reverse
     possibilities = self.reverse_dict.getlist(lookup_view)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 229, in _get_reverse_dict
     self._populate()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 208, in _populate
     for name in pattern.reverse_dict:
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/transurlvania/urlresolvers.py", line 214, in get_reverse_dict
     self._lang_reverse_dicts[lang] = self._build_reverse_dict_for_lang(lang)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/transurlvania/urlresolvers.py", line 171, in _build_reverse_dict_for_lang
     for pattern in reversed(self.url_patterns):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 283, in _get_url_patterns
     raise ImproperlyConfigured("The included urlconf %s doesn't have any patterns in it" % self.urlconf_name)
 ImproperlyConfigured: The included urlconf None doesn't have any patterns in it
 Zlib: Compressed 624 to 385 : URL /
```

---

## Solved

Usually Django returns the name of the app that's failing, in this case the app that were failing was **Adyengo**. The issue was that in the package files, **/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adyengo/sites.py**:

```
@property
def urls(self):

    if not settings.DEBUG:
        return
```

Because of the "empty" `return`, the django error is `... The included urlconf **None** doesn't...`

I commented/removed the lines `if not settings.DEBUG:    return` and then everything works as expected

Comment: did you add `ALLOWED_HOSTS` ?

Comment: I tried that 2 minutes ago, and it doesn't work. I tried like `ALLOWED_HOST = []` and `ALLOWED_HOST = ["*"]` and nothing

Comment: Can you paste your urls.py file please?

Comment: its `ALLOWED_HOSTS` not `ALLOWED_HOST` :) @Liarez

Comment: sorry i missed the 'S' when I wrote it here

Comment: I think its wsgi problem, check this blog: http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/requests-running-in-wrong-django.html and please google your error (WSGI Exception) and check for those solutions @Liarez

Comment: Why should wsgi works with `DEBUG = True` and fails with `DEBUG = False`? I think that it's more related with the urls than wsgi, anyway I'll check your link. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your patterns for include statements that point to non-existent modules or modules that do not have a urlpatterns member.

Comment: I have a full working project with urls/templates/views working. I don't see any include to non-existent modules, or modules without urlpatterns in it

Comment: You were right, I had an app that has a condition in the urlpatterns, and if `DEBUG = False` the app doesn't return any pattern, after commented that condition, I could make `DEBUG = False` without any error. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You use something like this (about media files):

```
if settings.DEBUG:
   urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
         {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
   url(r'', include('django.contrib.staticfiles.urls')),
```

Dont forget add media urls to existing urls, like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    /* some urls */
)

urlpatterns = +patterns('',
    /* media urls */
)
```